# How do I group iOS ui controls into a panel?

Tags: ios, user-interface, layout

In Windows I can put several controls into a panel/container such as a Grid, StackPanel, or WrapPanel. In Android I put the controls into a RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc. Then I can hide the panel or disable the panel and all the controls within are hidden or disabled. Changing child controls can be laid out relative to the panel and so changes to the panel position actually move the child controls.

I am having a difficult time figuring out what the similary concept would be for iOS.

Comment: Put your controls into a parent `UIView`. Move the parent view and all the controls go with it.

Comment: Well, that was too easy. I feel like such a newb with iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 9 is available UIStackView (documented here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview). I really recommend for your purpose. For grid layout you can make UIStackView full of other UIStackViews.

Also UIStackView handle rotations and can easily handle animations: https://medium.com/@nrewik/easy-animation-with-uistackview-8878b2856ae2#.l9g3me214